# Instructions for LEGO bag dated 2007 bought at a Thrift store

Tags: instructions

I need the instructions for a LEGO parts bag I purchased at a Thrift store[image]

Comment: It is from Palace Cinema. Pink circles are from the candy machine, doors for the limo and squares for the ground (you're missing the rare ones with cameras on it).

Answer (score 7):

Based on the parts, it looks suspiciously like an internal part bag for [10232 Palace Cinema](http://brickset.com/inventories/10232-1) - which means there's no specific instructions to make something with just those parts - the whole [set of instructions can be found online](http://brickset.com/ajax/sets/instructions?set=10232-1).

To clarify - a set like Palace Cinema will have a number of "Numbered" bags that correspond to part of the building instructions, and those bags sometimes contain smaller sealed bags of small parts - it looks like this is what you have there.

This is based on the two black doors - these seem to be fairly rare these days and the other parts (especially the 11 new dark red 2x2 tiles) fit nicely with the contents of that set.

Note that the year printed on the bag is the date the bag design was introduced - according to BrickSet the [pink circles](http://brickset.com/parts/4517996)  were first produced in 2008 - and of the [80 sets that it has appeared in](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4517996), only one of them [contains the black doors](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6024113) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but only some of the part are similar to the Palace Theatre. There were no Pink circle parts. This was a sealed bag, until I opened it to take the pic

Comment: A set that large has multiple bags of bricks inside. You've probably just got one.

Comment: I really don't think this is the 10232 Palace Cinema, this was released in 2013. The bag all these parts came in is dated 2007. And the Palace Cinema does not have the pink circles. Any other suggestion would be great, but keep in mind the year 2007. thanks

Comment: @Laura If you look at [this pdf](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6145733.pdf) on page 24 you can see the pink circles and the various tiles from your bag. Page 6 shows the black doors being used for the car.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. My son can had the pieces to the rest of his Lego and create something with them. I only spent $0.50 for the bag. It's all good

Comment: @Laura Just FYI: the bags sometimes have information printed on them that applies to the bag itself, as a part used in the packaging. Some proof that the 2007 date applies to the bag: the [bracket](http://rebrickable.com/parts/99781) piece in that photo wasn't available until 2012.